# How to use 256x256 icons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've created a multi-size icon with four sizes: 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 256x256. Every size comes with 3 color depths: 32bit, 8 bit and 4 bit, excluding 256x256 which is only 32 bit as I've read somewhere. I've added it to resources and set up as icon in application properties.

Now when I scale the view in Windows Explorer it is only showing 48x48 at max. For bigger sizes my icon is just siting in the middle.

How should I prepare and use icons to be displayed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

256x256 icon **has** to be saved with PNG compression

Answer (score 0):

Use a good icon editor (like "Gamani GIF Movie Gear"). It automatically generates a proper Windows icon, with 256x256 image saved in PNG format.